# Python, Evaluating parsed data against a predefined list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a large set of data which is being parsed by `feedparser` and is enumerated as a string. For instance:

```py
import feedparser

d = feedparser.parse('somefeed.xml')
```

will give elements such as `d.entries['title']`, `d.entries['url']`, and other `d.entries` which are strings.

I am wanting to compare these elements against a list I have defined to see if there is a match and I am not quite thinking something through correctly.

Below is what I tried, but got no output, any help is appreciated.

```py
for i in d.entries:
    my_list = ["Title One", "Title Two", "Etc"]
    if my_list in i['title'].split("-"):
        print(i)
```

If there is a match of parsed data and an element of my list, I want to print that element.